# How do I check if a filename matches a wildcard pattern?

Tags: .net

I know I can do

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.html")
```

and I'll get a list of files that match the *.html file pattern.

I'd like to do the inverse. Given file name abc.html, I'd like a method that will tell me if that filename matches the *.html pattern. for instance

```
class.method("abc.html", "*.html") // returns true
class.method("abc.xml", "*.html") // returns false
class.method("abc.doc", "*.?oc") // returns true
class.method("Jan24.txt", "Jan*.txt") // returns true
class.method("Dec24.txt", "Jan*.txt") // returns false
```

The functionality must exist in dotnet. I just don't know where it's exposed.

Converting the pattern to regex could be one way to go. However it just seems like there are a lot of edge cases and may be more trouble than it's worth.

Note: the filename in questions may not exist yet, so I can't just wrap a Directory.GetFiles call and check to see if the result set has any entries.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest way to go is to convert your wildcard to regex, and then apply it:

```cs
public static string WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
{
  return "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern).
  Replace("\\*", ".*").
  Replace("\\?", ".") + "$";
}
```

But if you cannot use regex for some reason, you can write your own implementation of wildcard matching. You can find one [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188256/A-Simple-Wildcard-Matching-Function?msg=3872751#xx3872751xx).

Here's another one ported from python implementation (Edit 2020-07: [fixed IndexOutOfRangeException](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sAgs2l)):

```cs
using System;
    
class App
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(Match("abc.html", "*.html")); // returns true
    Console.WriteLine(Match("abc.xml", "*.html")); // returns false
    Console.WriteLine(Match("abc.doc", "*.?oc")); // returns true
    Console.WriteLine(Match("Jan24.txt", "Jan*.txt")); // returns true
    Console.WriteLine(Match("Dec24.txt", "Jan*.txt")); // returns false  
  }
    
  static bool Match(string s1, string s2)
  {
    if (s2=="*" || s1==s2) return true;
    if (s1=="" || s2=="") return false;

    if (s1[0]==s2[0] || s2[0]=='?') return Match(s1.Substring(1),s2.Substring(1));
    if (s2[0]=='*') return Match(s1.Substring(1),s2) || Match(s1,s2.Substring(1));
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work for invalid filenames. `Match("aaa/bbb.txt", "*.txt");` will return *true*

Comment: Original question does not include path, only file name matching. But you can always extract file name using Path.GetFileName().

Comment: I said **invalid** filenames like `aaa/bbb.txt`. Not *path*

Comment: @I4V: I think it's not purpose of this RegEx, you can for invalid filename characters before doing the Match, searching for Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `searchPattern` of `GetFiles` does support full regex. Below code can be an alternative(but not very performant)

```
bool IsMatch(string fileName,string searchPattern)
{
    try
    {
        var di = Directory.CreateDirectory("_TEST_");
        string fullName = Path.Combine(di.FullName, fileName);
        using (File.Create(fullName)) ;
        bool isMatch = di.GetFiles(searchPattern).Any();
        File.Delete(fullName);
        return isMatch;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```